# What is the title of music played when Hermione's crying?

Tags: harry-potter, music, music-identification

[image]

This is the part of Half-Blood Prince. Hermione cried after seeing Ron and Lavender kissing together in a celebration. Hermione then casted the spell *oppugno* which if I'm not mistaken, it made the birds aggressive.

There's a background music playing when Harry saw Hermione crying on the stairs. The music intensified when Hermione asked Harry if he loves Ginny.

It's a solemn and sad music. It's just instrumental and I don't know what's the title of the music.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## "Harry and Hermione"

The track is called "Harry and Hermione" from the official film score soundtrack by Nicholas Hooper.

The "oppugno" part happens around 1m40s.